# How do I perform function parameter validation in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript class I want to use to manage a Checkbox. It looks like this:

```
export class TriStateCheckboxManager {

    constructor(public checkBox: HTMLInputElement) {
        if (checkBox.type != "checkbox") {
            // What now?
        }
    }
}
```

How can I *raise an error* if the checkbox's type is unequal to `checkbox`.

Comment: What do you want to do with that checkbox?

Comment: Clarify your question please

Comment: @Anzeo, much clearer can I make it? I want the `HTMLInputElement` object passed into the constructor have a `type` property of `checkbox` and I want to do something if it doesn't, like raise an exception, except I don't know if I can raise an exception, so I'm asking this question?

Comment: @FabianLauer I want to manage it as a tri-state checkbox, hence the name of the class.

Comment: "I don't know if I can raise an exception" -- what have you tried?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh, when I embark on learning something, I take the evolved approach and read and ask questions, instead of randomly trying things. Try it, find out how to start a fire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because TypeScript is a supertset of JavaScript, it supports all built-in JavaScript functions, types, objects, keywords and so on. The one you are looking for is the **`throw`** keyword, that will raise the desired exception.

Your code so far was good, so the following will do the job.

```
export class TriStateCheckboxManager {

    constructor(public checkBox: HTMLInputElement) {
        if (checkBox.type !== "checkbox") {
            // checkBox doesn't meet the reqruirements,
            // so raise an error. Optionally, you could
            // log a message, warning or whatever you want
            // to the console.
            console.warn("checkBox.type doesn't match.", checkBox, this);
            throw "checkBox.type doesn't match."    // Throw anything you want here
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: It's strongly recommended to use `!==` and `===` for comparisons in JavaScript (thus TypeScript) instead of `!=` and `==`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis) for more.

EDIT:
As MiMo said below, you can throw whatever type you want, so an object would be a suitable canditate too.

I found that [this](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/03/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors/) article looks promising if you're into JavaScript / TypeScript error handling. Here's the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) page for throwing errors in JavaScript.

Comment: I'd throw an object, not just a string

Comment: @MiMo: Good point. I'm gonna state that you can throw whatever you want.  ( Even tomatoes? :)   )